# How to see the content of the SDRAM in my DE1-SOC while running (JTAG Altera cable)?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, sdram, quartus

I have made a simple design in Quartus Prime, in verilog code, not using megawizard, but directly accessing the pins of the SDRAM. I am saving 2 x 16 bits binary numbers on 3 of the 4 banks of the SDRAM.

I have downloaded the design on my board DE1-SOC, and now I want to read the content of the SDRAM to see if the numbers actually passed to the SDRAM chip.

What should I do in this case?

There is a In-System memory content editor but I think it only works for on-chip RAM, or am I wrong?

Comment: What's wrong in doing it by SW using a Nios processor?

Comment: I don't know think you can access the SDRAM via jtag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working DRAM-Controller, there are several possibilities. Instantiate a NIOS-II with debugging-option, and you will be able to even debug using Eclipse CDT. If I remember correctly, there is also an Avalon-MM master that lets you peek into memory from System Console.

If however your design *is* the Controller and you want to debug it, there is no option to access the memory by other means, bypassing your design.

BTW: Using QSYS does not force you to start over, you can embed a Verilog component in a QSYS-project and vice versa. I prefer to have a QSYS-component as top-level entity.